# How can I create a tile-able version of this background?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

This question has 2 parts:

1. How can I create the background of this image in Photoshop?
2. How can I make it tile-able?

By the way, are there any sites that show off tile-able backgrounds that have a "concrete" type look, or something similar to the image above?

[image]

Comment: What background? It is black

Comment: If you ignore all the white stuff, the writing, the box, the arrows, etc... there's just a pixel-y background. that's what I'm referring to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create the background effect, you will need to use some layers and the noise effect.

1) Create a new layer on top of the default one (Shift+Ctrl+N).

2) Change the color of the new layer to #142E51 (Paint Bucket Tool or `G`).

3) Create a third layer (you can call it "noise layer") and fill it with white color (#FFFFFF).

4) Go to Filter > Noise > Add Noise and a Add Noise popup box will appear, set the Amount 25, select the uniform radio button and finally press OK button.

[image]

5) Now go to Layer > New Adjustment Layer > Hue/Saturation or just simply press (Ctrl+U) and you will see Hue/Saturation popup box, now set the value of Saturation -100 and OK.

[image]

6) Selecting the Noise Layer, go to Image > Adjustments > Invert (Ctrl+I). Still keep selecting the Noise Layer change the Blending Option to Linear Dodge (Add) and opacity to 45%.

[image]

Once you have made this, you can simply make a square selection and turn it into a pattern to use it anywhere you like: Edit > Define Pattern.

Source: http://www.tutorialsbucket.com/noise-texture-background-effect-in-adobe-photoshop-cs5

Comment: +1. The Noise filter was a revelation when I found it. Wait, you can use Photoshop to make things look *worse?!*

Comment: Same here! I couldn't figure it out, that hideous thing, and now I'm crazy about it :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't actually seen this in Photoshop but in the Gimp you can just take a block of background, put it in an image and go `Filters -> Map -> Make Seamless`.